# Java блок synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Пытаюсь в блоке `synchronized(){}` синхронизировать объект `ArrayList`. В отдельном потоке захватываю этот объект в `synchronized`, записываю значение (`first`), кидаю поток в сон на 1 сек. и закидываю следующее значение (`second`). Главный поток, после запуска потока с `synchronized`, кидаю в сон на 1 сек. и записываю значение (`last`).

Как я понял из изучения: объект переданный в блок `synchronized` не доступен другому потоку, до выхода объекта из блока. Т.е. очередь массива будет: `first`, `second`, `last`. В моем же примере очередь: `first`, `last`, `second`. Т.е. главный поток обратился к объекту массива до выхода объекта из блока `synchronized`.

Как правильно организовать синхронизацию объекта, т.е. что бы к нему не было доступа до выхода из блока?

Код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        CheckSynchronized cs = new CheckSynchronized();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (cs.al) {
                    cs.al.add("First");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cs.al.add("Second");
                }
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cs.al.add("Last");
        cs.al.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class CheckSynchronized {
    public ArrayList<String> al;

    CheckSynchronized() {
        al = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Как я понял из изучения: объект переданный в блок synchronized не доступен другому потоку, до выхода объекта из блока.

Нет, вы неправильно поняли. Объект, на котором вы синхронизируетесь, никак не связан с содержимым этого объекта. Просто Java так странно устроена, что можно абсолютно любой объект использовать как монитор синхронизации и без разницы, что это за объект и для чего ещё он может использоваться.

Секции синхронизации используются для реализации шаблона «взаимного исключения» (mutual exclusion, mutex): одновременно не могут работать две секции синхронизации, синхронизованные на одном объекте. Если вы обернёте запись в `al` в `synchronized(cs.al)`, как советует @Vartlok, вы добьётесь взаимного исключения. Тогда вам будет гарантировано, что либо записи `First` и `Second` появятся до записи `Last`, либо они появятся после (порядок `First, Last, Second` вы гарантированно не увидите). Но тем не менее конкретно «до» или «после» никто не обещает. Хотя вы секунду поспали в одном потоке, нет гарантий, что второй поток вообще за эту секунду начал выполняться. С очень большой вероятностью он начнёт, но никто не гарантирует. Вдруг система слишком загружена, например.

Чтобы гарантировать порядок, вам нужны другие механизмы. Например, можно воспользоваться [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
CheckSynchronized cs = new CheckSynchronized();
// Заводим счётчик на 1
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cs.al.add("First");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cs.al.add("Second");
        // Закончили операцию — уменьшили счётчик
        latch.countDown();
    }

}).start();

try {
    // Дожидаемся, пока в счётчике будет 0. 
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

cs.al.add("Last");
cs.al.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Таким образом мы обеспечили гарантированный порядок, а синхронизация на самом деле не нужна.

В данном случае есть и более простой механизм — [`Thread.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29):

```
CheckSynchronized cs = new CheckSynchronized();

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cs.al.add("First");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cs.al.add("Second");
    }

});
thread.start();

try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

cs.al.add("Last");
cs.al.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Так как второй тред больше ничего не собирается делать, можно просто дождаться его завершения. Но если во втором треде планируется ещё что-то, то для упорядочивания событий `CountDownLatch` гибче. Ещё гибче [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) или [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).

Answer (score 5):

Ну поведение кода полностью соответствует тому, что вы написали. `synchronize` исправно проверяет лок объекта, и, если его нет, он его забирает себе. Только когда вы добавляете в список `"Last"`, никто не проверяет что объект залочен. Т.е. чтобы код отработал так как вам надо, надо сделать так:

```
synchronized (cs.al) {
    cs.al.add("Last");
}
```

Тогда перед добавлением будет проверяться залоченость объекта и поток встанет пока объект не станет доступным.

Т.к. вы изучаете многопоточность, будет полезно почитать разницу между `wait()` и `sleep()` [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep), чтобы потом не удивляться.