# Блокируется ли объект в synchronized блоке созданный в конструкторе класса?

Tags: java, synchronized

Может быть глупый вопрос но всё же спрошу.

Имеется `synchronized` блок, в котором блокируется объект. В конструкторе этого самого объекта создается другой объект.

Вопрос блокируется ли он так же?

пример:

```
public class SomeClass{

private SecondClass sClass;

public SomeClass(){
      sClass = new SecondClass();    
}

.
. // some action
.
try{
   synchronized(this){
      this.wait(sometime);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Нет, не блокируется.

Answer (score 4):

Не блокируется.
На этом сайте был вопрос на другую тему, но [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449589/189882) на него может помочь вам:

> Объект, на котором вы синхронизируетесь, никак не связан с содержимым
>   этого объекта. Просто Java так странно устроена, что можно абсолютно
>   любой объект использовать как монитор синхронизации и без разницы, что
>   это за объект и для чего ещё он может использоваться.