# Шилдт об операторе synchronized

Tags: java, synchronized

Шилдт утверждает, что внутри блока synchronized должен быть метод объекта того же класса, что и объект, на который ссылается оператор synchronized.
[image: Шилдт java 8 p303]

Но у меня всё прекрасно работает и тогда, когда метод принадлежит объекту совсем другого класса. Синхронизация происходит. Я не тем местом читаю?

Вот немного изменённый мною код Шилдта, который он приводит в пример. Только я добавил ещё один класс CallYou, метод объекта которого и синхронизирует synchronized. А в операторе synchronized указана ссылка на старый объект класса CallMe. Имеем ситуацию, когда внутри блока метод другого класса, но результат выводится как по книжке.

```
class CallMe{

}


class CallYou {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}


class Caller implements Runnable{
    String msg;
    CallMe target;
    Thread t;

    CallYou target2 =  new CallYou();

    public Caller(CallMe targ, String s){
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){

        synchronized(target) {
            target2.call(msg);
        }
    }
}

public class testR1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CallMe target = new CallMe();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Welcome");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "to synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World!");

        try {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я 10 раз перечитал Шилда, но так и не понял про что он. Попробую нормально расписать как оно работает.

Comment: Все верно, в synchronized можно напихать чего угодно. Но какой от этого смысл, если запихнуть туда публичный метод, да еще и чужой? Его кто угодно сможет вызвать в обход синхронизации.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449589/177499 - вот тут вроде описано как работает синхронайз блок, думаю будет понятно почему у вас оно тоже работает.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответы. Я уже понял, что он будет работать в любом случае. Но мне казалось, что я в теме что-то ещё упускаю. Ведь неспроста там есть этот абзац про одинаковые классы. Возможно, что некачественный перевод.

Comment: иногда нужно синхронизироваться по внешнему объекту. т,е, объект который стоит после synchronized и объект с которым работают внутри блока - разные.

Comment: >иногда нужно синхронизироваться по внешнему объекту
И нет никаких ограничений на то, какой это объект? Он не должен быть того же класса, что и объект внутри блока?

Comment: А вы поменьше верьте Шилдту, он известен не очень правильными формулировками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синхронизация нужна для того, чтобы блок кода выполнялся только тогда, когда отслеживаемый объект гарантированно "свободен" (не изменяется). Внутри блока может быть что угодно, но наиболее рационально использовать синхронизацию по назначению и делать что-то с объектом. При этом существует возможность работать с ним без синхронизации, но никаких гарантий, что какой-то другой поток сейчас с ним не работает, не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Особенно за последнее предложение. Я до него дошёл путём опытов с кодом. Но вот у Шилдта в главе, посвящённой блоку синхронизации, об этом очень важном моменте не написано. И может казаться, что блок синхронизации работает также, как модификатор synchronized.
Посмотрел в английской версии - написано тоже самое. Только воды чуть меньше. Видимо, просто по какой-то причине неправильно сформулированная мысль.